# Update Selected Row DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I building a small app writen in Visual Basic.NET, but i need your help. I have DataGridView to display my database and i want make "update" button to update from DataGridView to database. But before update, i want to selected row in DataGridView like this:

[image: Selected row]

and show to textbox. So, i made a change from textbox for update my database. How to do it?

Here is my code for update:

```
Private Sub btnPesEdit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPesEdit.Click
        Koneksi()

        Dim konfEdit As DialogResult = MsgBox("Apakah data yang di-update sudah benar?",
                                             MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, "Konfirmasi")

        Try
            str = "UPDATE data_pesanan SET (@namakons, @almtkons, @tglpesan, @jenispaket, @jmlpesan, @totaluang) WHERE (@kodekons)"


            comm = New MySqlCommand(str, conn)

            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kodeKons", txtPesKodeKonsu.Text)
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@namakons", txtPesNamaKonsu.Text)
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@almtkons", txtPesAlmtKonsu.Text)
            dtPesTglPesan.CustomFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tglpesan", dtPesTglPesan.Value)
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jenispaket", lblPesJenisPkt.Text)
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jmlpesan", Convert.ToInt32(txtPesJmlPesan.Text))
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totaluang", Convert.ToInt32(lblPesTotal.Text))

            comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
            conn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.InnerException.Message)
            'MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

And here is my code to display from database into DataGridView:

```
Private Sub tablePesanan()
        Koneksi()

        comm = New MySqlCommand("select * from data_pesanan", conn)
        dataAdap = New MySqlDataAdapter(comm)
        Dim dataTbl As New DataTable
        dataAdap.Fill(dataTbl)
        tblPesList.DataSource = dataTbl
        tblPesList.ReadOnly = True
    End Sub
```

Note:
I'm sorry if my English is bad. I hope you understand what I'm saying.

Comment: When posting code, it is recommended to paste the actual code into the question. Most will not re-type your code and your question will get little response. I recommend you research “Binding” for a `TextBox`… example…  `Binding b = new Binding("Text", GridTable, "column1");  textBox1.DataBindings.Add(b);`… where “GridTable” is a `DataTable` data source, and “column1” is the field in the table that you want displayed. I also recommend a visit to the SO [HELP – How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: thank you for correcting me :)

Comment: Why don't you make the changes directly in the grid?

Comment: I'm sorry. I dont understand. Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you should use data-binding. You should bind your `DataTable` to a `BindingSource` and then bind that to the grid and the other controls, e.g.

```vb
myBindingSource.DataSource = myDataTable
myDataGridView.DataSource = myBindingSource
myTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", myBindingSource, "ColumnName")
```

You can bind as many individual controls to as many columns as you like that way. Just be sure to bind the appropriate control property. It is `Text` for a `TextBox` but `SelectedValue` for a `ComboBox`, `Value` for a `DateTimePicker`, etc. Also be aware that a `DateTimePicker` doesn't really support binding nullable data so, if your data might contain nulls in the date column, you will need some manual intervention.

When it's time to save data, you need to make sure that any pending edit is committed before actually saving, e.g.

```vb
Validate()
myBindingSource.EndEdit()
myDataAdapter.Update(myDataTable)
```